# Link attachment images to specific woocommerce products?

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

is it possible to link attachment images, added through media, to specific products in wordpress/woocommerce?

each product has a featured image but on the home page i want to display a select few which show a different image.

is there a way to pull in a specific attachment image to a product?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.. Go to media library and click edit image you want to add link. In that editing section you can find a option called link to where you can add link of the woocommerce product.